# Unable to click accordions developed in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver, accordion

I am trying to automate an angular js app using selenium. But I am unable to click on the accordion buttons. Error message says the element is not clickable. Can anyone please help?

Comment: Could you share your HTML and tried code as well..:)

Comment: Is the element visible on the browser before you're sending the click? Could also be the case that it's not ready to be clicked when you're sending it..